# LINQ to SQL dividing filters for better performance

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have these below LINQ to SQL queries

```
var kayitlarFiltreli = from rows in db.TBLP1CARIs
                       orderby rows.ID descending
                       where rows.HESAPADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) ||
                                              (rows.CARITURU == "Bireysel" ?
                                               rows.B_ADSOYAD.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) :
                                               rows.K_FIRMAADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())) ||
                                               rows.ID.ToString().Contains(filter)
                       select rows;

var kayitlarBakiyeli = from rows in kayitlarFiltreli
                       select new
                                   {
                                       HESAPNO = rows.ID,
                                       HESAPADI = rows.HESAPADI,
                                       CARIADI = (rows.CARITURU == "Bireysel" ? rows.B_ADSOYAD : rows.K_FIRMAADI),
                                       Bakiye = get_bakiye(rows.ID, rows.LISTEPARABIRIMI)
                                   };

var kayitlarSon = from rows in kayitlarBakiyeli
                  select new
                            {  rows.HESAPNO,
                               rows.HESAPADI,
                               rows.CARIADI,
                               Bakiye = rows.Bakiye.Contains(".") == true ?
                                        rows.Bakiye.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.') :
                                        rows.Bakiye

                            };
```

I am having performance problem I mean the queries response at least after 15secs, and when it is deployed to the website it takes at least 5 secs for the page which is using these queries to fill a `GridView`.`get_bakiye(p1,p2,..)` is a long method with a `for`, a `foreach` and a Linq-to-SQL query in it.I think the most of time is spent on `get_bakiye` I struggled with it already and reduced the response time like 2 secs, however it is still slow.And I am trying to get the above queries work faster.

I tried

```
var kayitlarSirali =  from rows in db.TBLP1CARIs
                      orderby rows.ID descending
                      select rows;

var kayitlarFiltreli = from rows in kayitlarSirali
                       where rows.HESAPADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) ||
                                        (rows.CARITURU == "Bireysel" ? 
                                         rows.B_ADSOYAD.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) : 
                                         rows.K_FIRMAADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())) ||
                                         rows.ID.ToString().Contains(filter)
                       select rows;
```

And the rest is the same.
Basically I just seperated the filtering part with `Contains()`, which I am not sure if that helps so much.

Is it good to seperate `where`'s I mean filters when querying the database, and is it better for performance to query the database once and get the results into an in-memory IQueryable and do the rest on it?

What do you recommend for these queries to work faster?
This is the `get_bakiye()` method which is not something I wrote fully but I am supposed to make it perform faster.

```
public static string get_bakiye(int cari_id, string birim_kod)
        {
            return get_bakiye(cari_id, DAL.DAOCari.GetEntity(cari_id).LISTEPARABIRIMI, null,false);
        }

public static string get_bakiye(int cari_id, string birim_kod, List<BAL.P_CariBakiyeTablosu> custom_rapor, bool borcluTespit)
        {
            VeriyazDBDataContext db = new VeriyazDBDataContext(); db.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

            decimal return_bakiye = 0;

            if (birim_kod == null || birim_kod.Trim() == "") //default
                birim_kod = "TL";

            //devir bakiyesini hesapla:
            List<BAL.P_CariBakiyeTablosu> bakiyeler = new List<BAL.P_CariBakiyeTablosu>();
            if (custom_rapor == null)
                bakiyeler = CariBakiyeRaporuOlustur(cari_id, true);
            else
                bakiyeler = custom_rapor;

            bakiyeler.RemoveAt(0);

            List<TBLP1DOVIZTANIMLARI> dovizTanimlariTumListe = DAL.DAOdoviztanimlari.SelectAll().ToList();
            //devirleri hesaplarken döviztanimlari tablosundaki varsayılan kuru kullanıyor
            for (int i = 0; i < bakiyeler.Count; i++)
            {
                if (bakiyeler[i].DOVIZ == birim_kod)
                {
                    return_bakiye = return_bakiye + Convert.ToDecimal(bakiyeler[i].DEVIR);
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal from_kur = 1;
                    from_kur = from_kur = dovizTanimlariTumListe.Where(rows => rows.TBLP1DOVIZLER.KOD == bakiyeler[i].DOVIZ).FirstOrDefault().VARSAYILANKUR.GetValueOrDefault(1);

                    decimal to_kur = 1;
                    to_kur = dovizTanimlariTumListe.Where(rows => rows.TBLP1DOVIZLER.KOD == birim_kod).First().VARSAYILANKUR.GetValueOrDefault(1);


                    return_bakiye = return_bakiye + (Convert.ToDecimal(bakiyeler[i].DEVIR) * (from_kur / to_kur));
                }
            }

            //islem bakiyesini hesapla:

            var islemler = from rows in db.TBLP1ISLEMs
                           where
                           rows.CARI_ID == cari_id &&
                           rows.TEKLIF.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false &&
                           rows.SOZLESME.GetValueOrDefault(false) == false &&
                           (rows.SIPARISDURUMU == "İşlem Tamamlandı" || 
                            rows.SIPARISDURUMU == "Hazırlanıyor" || 
                            rows.SIPARISDURUMU == "" || 
                            rows.SIPARISDURUMU == null)
                           select rows;

            //var dovizKuruOlanIslemler = from dovizKuruRow in db.TBLP1DOVIZKURUs
            //                            select dovizKuruRow.ISLEM_ID;

            foreach (var item in islemler)
            {
                decimal from_kur = 1;
                decimal fromKurVarsayilan = 1;
                //belirtilen dövizin varsayılanını çekiyor
                fromKurVarsayilan = dovizTanimlariTumListe.Where(rows => rows.TBLP1DOVIZLER.KOD == item.PARABIRIMI).FirstOrDefault().VARSAYILANKUR.GetValueOrDefault(1);

                try
                {
                    from_kur = item.KURDEGERI.Value;
                    //aşağıdaki satırda dövizkuru tablosundan işleme ait kuru çekerek hesap yapıyordu, işlem tablosuna KURDEGERİ kolonu ekleyince
                    //buna gerek kalmadı, yukarıdaki satırda işleme ait kur değeri işlem tablosundan çekiyor.
                    //from_kur = item.TBLP1DOVIZKURUs.Where(rows => rows.DOVIZBIRIM == item.PARABIRIMI).FirstOrDefault().KUR.GetValueOrDefault();
                }
                catch
                {
                    from_kur = fromKurVarsayilan;
                }

                //carinin para biriminin varsayılan kurunu çekiyor
                decimal to_kur = 1;
                decimal toKurVarsayilan = 1;

                toKurVarsayilan = dovizTanimlariTumListe.Where(rows => rows.TBLP1DOVIZLER.KOD == birim_kod).FirstOrDefault().VARSAYILANKUR.GetValueOrDefault(1);

                to_kur = toKurVarsayilan;


                if (item.CARIISLEMTURU == "BORC")
                {
                    return_bakiye = return_bakiye + (Convert.ToDecimal(item.GENELTOPLAM) * (from_kur / to_kur));
                }
                if (item.CARIISLEMTURU == "ALACAK")
                {
                    return_bakiye = return_bakiye - (Convert.ToDecimal(item.GENELTOPLAM) * (from_kur / to_kur));
                }
            }

            string returnBakiyeParaFormatli = DAL.Format.ParaDuzenle.ParaFormatDuzenle(return_bakiye.ToString());
            if (borcluTespit==true)
            {
                return return_bakiye.ToString();
            }
            if (returnBakiyeParaFormatli.Contains(".") == true)
            {
                return returnBakiyeParaFormatli.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.') + " " + birim_kod;

            }
            else
            {
                return returnBakiyeParaFormatli + " " + birim_kod;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the queries taking the time? Either profile your database server, or put some debug printouts (with timestamps) to make sure you're optimising the right thing.

Comment: Does get_bakiye also perform queries against the DB?  This could be a big performance problem because if it does it will perform at least 1 query for each row in your table.

Comment: Try runnnig the LINQ queries in LINQPad and take a look at the SQL that it's generating.  It will become obvious if it's performing one query for each row.  You can also then copy the SQL into management studio and profile it to see where you can pick up on performance, management studio will suggest adding some indexes that may help.

Comment: @DoctaJonex Yes it does, I think that is the problem but this has to be done.

Comment: @Simon I will try that Righarts, thanks.I think I am sure it's because of get_bakiye but it seems to me that it cannot be reduced more so I turned to these queries in my question.

Comment: I think you need to post code for get_bakiye for anybody to make an informed decision

Comment: @jaywayco I can, well then I will have to post another two long methods it uses in it :) I dont want to bother people that is why I am didn't post it.I worked on it as much as I could.

Comment: @Simon @DoctaJonez @jaywayco I posted `get_bakiye()` method, thanks

Comment: List<TBLP1DOVIZTANIMLARI> dovizTanimlariTumListe = DAL.DAOdoviztanimlari.SelectAll().ToList();, What is DAL.DAOdoviztanimlari? Is it a Linq Entity on the datasource? i.e. Table<DAOdoviztanimlari>?

Comment: `TBLP1DOVIZTANIMLARI` is a table on my database and it is on my datasource `.dbml` file. @jaywayco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general i think you need to understand what causes Linq to Sql to execute a query against your database. In general, extension methods such as `ToList()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()` will cause Linq To Sql to execute a command against the database. One line that does concern me is:

```
List<TBLP1DOVIZTANIMLARI> dovizTanimlariTumListe = DAL.DAOdoviztanimlari.SelectAll().ToList();
```

This seems to be getting every row from the database table that `DAOdoviztanimlari` is mapped to. The result of this is then queried in memory.

This then happens for every record in the queries that call `get_bakiye()`!

Ultimately (perfect world) you want `get_bakiye()` to not contain any of the extension methods i have mentioned and to return `IQueryable<string>` then let Linq to SQL descide how it optimizes and executes the SQL.

Comment: so you are saying I should get rid of those extension methods?but how Mr.jaywayco I need them?

Comment: yes, think of linq to sql as an easy way of visuallizing your sql queries in a type safe way. Let linq to sql decide how to write the actual sql and let the DBMS decide how to optimize the query. Eliminating these extension methods where posible will reduce the number of database hits. This may be no mean feat though ;)

Comment: Look at dovizTanimlariTumListe.Where(rows => rows.TBLP1DOVIZLER.KOD == bakiyeler[i].DOVIZ).FirstOrDefault().VARSAYILANKUR.GetValueOrDefault(1); this could be changed to DAL.DAOdoviztanimlari.FirstOrDefault().VARSAYILANKUR.GetValueOrDefault(1); This has already removed the need to get every record for that table and remove a very significant database hit.

Comment: Thanks I will change those things, and reduce them jaywayco

Answer (score 1):

First profile your database and see how long the generated queries take to execute and how often do they execute.

If the results from the profiling show that you are executing the same query against the database or the query takes too long to execute perhaps you should consider loading values into memory and access them from there. Or even consider compiled queries as an alternative if that's plausible.

I had a similar problem a little while ago that I solved by creating a separate class that handles the loading of values that I needed into a collection and updating the values when necessary.

Comment: you have no idea of the size of the dataset. Loading the data here is a bad idea as it is an inline function within other queries